Que veut dire "caser" dans cette phrase?
Je lis L'anomalie par Hervé Le Tellier. Je ne comprends pas le mot "caser" dans le passage suivant:

— Ça ne peut pas être à cause… d’Ilena Leskova ? insiste Joséphine Mikaleff. L’Anomalie a pour anagramme Amo Ilena L. « J’aime Ilena L. »


Miesel éclate de rire.


— Non ? C’est vrai ? Qui a trouvé un truc pareil ?


— Ilena l’a sous-entendu dans une interview.


— Heureusement que le latin existe pour caser amo.

Je crois que la dernière phrase veut dire quelque chose comme "We're lucky that we got amo from Latin," mais quand je cherche "caser" dans le dictionnaire, je ne trouve pas "recevoir" comme traduction.

The idea is "fortunately we have the Latin language to tuck a-m-o in the anagram".

Tu as bien saisi ce que ça veut dire dans ce contexte.  Caser, c'est trouver une place pour quelque chose, dans ce cas, la racine du verbe amo, amare en latin.  On traduit le sens ; on ne traduit pas les mots.
Le TLFi montre plusieurs définitions de caser qui correspondent, voici les deux premières :

A.− [Le compl. d'obj. désigne une chose] Ranger dans des cases. Caser des papiers.
− Absol., JEUX (trictrac). Mettre deux dames dans une case au trictrac.
B.− P. ext., fam.

[Le compl. d'obj. désigne une chose]
a) Mettre à telle ou telle place.


Recevoir, ce n'est pas toujours get/got mais les traductions automatiques vont très vite essayer avec.  To get est super  polysémique en anglais dont recevoir n'en est qu'une façon souvent trop directe comme traduction.
Heureusement le latin existe pour caser recevoir !

Je comprends cette dernière phrase comme signifiant que amo peut être rangé dans une "case", c'est-à-dire que l'on peut trouver une place pour ce amo grâce au latin. On peut ainsi "caser" (ranger) amo à la bonne place dans le décodage de l'anagramme.
